# Can't get DBMS_LOB.FILEEXISTS to return 1

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a file `/home/oracle/x.sql` and on sqlplus I'm executing:

`CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY BLOB_DIR AS '/home/oracle';`

`SELECT DBMS_LOB.FILEEXISTS(BFILENAME('BLOB_DIR', 'x.sql')) from dual;`

but it prints `0` (File doesn't exists)

what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: The file is on the same server as the database? Or is your SQL*Plus on a client machine and you're trying to access a local file, which can't be done?

Comment: My SQL*Plus is on a client machine, but the file is on the same server as the database

Comment: Have you verified that Oracle has filesystem-level read/write privileges on /home/oracle and on x.sql? Have you tried opening the file using UTL_FILE?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry guys, looks like I was connecting trough SQL*Plus to one machine while looking at the files on a very similarly named but different machine. My bad, thank you for the tips tho!

Comment: How do I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

As other people have stated:

- Make sure Oracle has filesystem-level read/write privileges on the folder and file.
- Make sure the file you're trying to reach is on the server side and not on the client.
- And make sure you are connected to the machine you think you are connected to!

Thank you for your help.